# How to make 3D Triangle pyramid?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, keyframe

I need to make precisely this [Pyramid-triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1NxO.png) in order to perform animation for this triangle, it becomes very challenging since mine is rotating with X line, but instead I should rotate it with Y line, basically it should rotate or flip to the right side. My main objective is to make it look like in 3D, how to achieve this? or maybe there are some other ways to make this ?

Run the snippet, and please help me what's wrong?

```css
.triangle-pyramid {
 transition-property: transform;
 transition: 0.6s;
}
.triangle-pyramid:hover {
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 width:inherit;
 height:inherit;
 top:50px;
 left:-25px;               
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;
 -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;
 -webkit-transform:rotate3d(1,0,0,-120deg);
 -moz-transform:rotate3d(1,0,0,-120deg);
 border:1px solid rgb(147,81,166,.5);
 display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div>
   <img class="triangle-pyramid" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1NxO.png" alt="objectives SMM" >
</div>
```

Comment: Your codepen is empty !

Comment: @abhishekkannojia please see it, now!